# Reading nested name-value pair in Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, servlet-3.0

I need to read the HTTP POST request data in servlet. Data is in name-value pair. Following is the data sent to server ( I picked this data from Network tab in google chrome's Inspect Element tool).

```
data1[roll_no]:32
data1[section]:A
data1[standard]:2
data1[marks][]:54
data1[marks][]:23
```

I am able to read all the values except list of `marks`.
My attempt to read the values is:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log(this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    Enumeration<String> name = request.getParameterNames();
    while(name.hasMoreElements()){
        String param = name.nextElement();
        log(param+" = "+request.getParameter(param));
    }
}
```

And, here i need some clue to iterate over whole list of marks when `param` is `data1[marks][]`

Answer (score 1):

Use getParameterValues()

```
String param = ...;
if(param.equals("data1[marks][]")) {
    String[] marks = request.getParameterValues(param);
    for(String m : marks) { //iterate over param data1[marks][]
        //do
    }

}
```

`getParameterValues` can also come in handy when obtaining values of a `<select multiple>` element

```
<select name="multiParams" multiple>
    ...
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are parameters which are not unique in this case `data1[marks][]`.

Can you try using `request.getparameterValues(param)` which is used for scenarios where there an non-unique parameter keys

`request.getParameterValues(param)` would return an array of Strings. Refer the [ServletRequest API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29) for details.

Comment: i tried above mentioned solution, but i am not getting desired result. also i think i should modify data[marks][0], data1[marks][1] and so on, then in that case how would i get to know that data1[marks] has how many values in it. If i can get that then it would be better for me.